# Unable to add header on Apache webserver hosted by azure

Tags: apache, azure, clickjacking

I am trying to enable Anti clickjacking on a website hosted by Azure.

Its a shared hosting package run on Apache server. Problem is that i cant find the correct conf file to modify and add this line of code to:

```
header always set x-frame-options "SAMEORIGIN"
```

we found a file called apache2.conf and added this but after restarting apache server the line is removed from the conf.

Anyone any ideas what i can do ?

Answer (score 0):

The `header` code you are trying to add should be applied to a .htaccess file, placed in the folder where you want the action to happen. In your case it's likely the root of your site.

Be warned, though, that I've just ran in to an issue whereby mod_headers.c are not enabled in my container. So even if you put the code above in to a .htaccess file, it still may not work.

I'm interested in knowing where you found the apache2.conf file though. I can't see that on mine (but that may be due to me replying a custom docker container).